# I would like to display one of my HTML pages for a certain period of time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to display one of my HTML pages for a certain period of time without having to click anything, after that you should be redirected to another HTML page. how could i do all this?

```
I'm trying to add some kind of "fake loading screen".
```

Comment: Hampering a user getting to your site is not particularly great UX.

Comment: it will be a .exe

Comment: @Glower this is a bit too broad for me to have the ability to help you out. Can you please add a couple of things: `Can you provide more context for "a certain period of time"?`, `Can you provide a snippet of the code you are working on?`, and `Can you provide further context for the text snippet you provided? In my head in conflicts a bit with what you initially mentioned you would like to do.`

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan i build a .exe and if anyone open the .exe he should see 2 or 3 seconds this "fake loding scrren" and then he should he be forwarded to the actual program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` function to achiecve this.

```
<script>
    // redirect after 5 seconds (5000 miliseconds)
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "#redirect url";
    }, 5000)     
</script>
```